# What is the definition of FitResiduals

Tags: fitting

What is the definition of `FitResiduals` in Mathematica?
 I could not find its definition in the Mathematica help. Is it the same as chi squared?

Comment: It's in the help: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RegressionCommon/ref/FitResiduals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the documentation for [`FitResiduals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RegressionCommon/ref/FitResiduals.html) leads directly to [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearModelFit.html) and [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), where it is stated that

> `"FitResiduals"` --  difference between actual and predicted responses

For example,

```
pts = Table[{x, x + RandomReal[.1 {-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 5, .2}];

fm = LinearModelFit[pts, x, x]
```

Now  `fm["FitResiduals"]`  is the same as  `#2 - fm[#1] & @@@ pts`.